# ejabberd users autocreation/export from dovecot

Tags: ejabberd

I want ejabberd (ejabberd 14.12) to use Dovecot's table 'users' for authentication (which is done already) but keep all ejabberd's data in different mysql database.

Is there anything, like autocreation option? For example, if user was successfully authenticated via external script, create that user in ejabberd's database? Or I have to make this up by my own? Im new in ejabberd

For authentication, I have this in ejabberd.yml

```
auth_method: external
extauth_program: "/opt/ejabberd/bin/auth_mysql_dovecot.php"
```

Will this allow me to use odbc as back-end?

Answer (score 0):

I went the simple way.. What I needed is a local replacement for gmail+google chat for corporate users:

1. Dovecot with mysql authentication
2. Roundcube with plugin [converse.js](https://github.com/priyadi/roundcube-converse.js-xmpp-plugin)
3. Ejabberd with external auth:

   `auth_method: external
   extauth_program: "/opt/ejabberd/bin/auth_mysql_dovecot.php"`

[Here](http://pastebin.com/22fWHQq3) is my `auth_mysql_dovecot.php` script. It doesn't use SASL to connect to dovecot. Its just simply connecting to dovecot mysql database. Important: Dovecot password encryption MUST BE 'CRAM-MD5'. *Sorry, its the third version of the script. I didn't put the notes, where did I steal the code*

No any registration needed. Once users login to their *roundcube*, they automatically will be logged into to ejabberd. Similar to google chat. If they change their passwords for Dovecot/Roundcube, the password will be changed for ejabberd as well.

I just let ejabberd to use its own native database